# xhtml + jsf get values from a controller class

Tags: jsf, foreach, xhtml

I want to ask you about how xhtml works.

this is my tablero.xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            <h:outputText value="Dak's Hangman"></h:outputText>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="body">
            <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:head  id="demo" >Opportunities: </h:head>            
            <h:outputText value="#{partidaController.getRemainingOp()}"/>    
            <br/>
            <h:outputText value="#{partidaController.getNombreJugador()}"/>                   
            <br/>
            <c:forEach var="x" items="#{partidaController.getLetrasColocadas()}" >
                <h:inputText disabled="true" size="1" value="${x}"/>
            </c:forEach>
            <br/>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton id="b1" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="a" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('a')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b2" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="b" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('b')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b3" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="c" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('c')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b4" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="d" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('d')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b5" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="e" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('e')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b6" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="f" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('f')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b7" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="g" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('g')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b8" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="h" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('h')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b9" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="i" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('i')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b10" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="j" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('j')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b11" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="k" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('k')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b12" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="l" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('l')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b13" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="m" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('m')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b14" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="n" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('n')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b15" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="o" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('o')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b16" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="p" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('p')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b17" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="q" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('q')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b18" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="r" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('r')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b19" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="s" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('s')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b20" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="t" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('t')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b21" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="u" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('u')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b22" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="v" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('v')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b23" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="w" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('w')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b24" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="x" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('x')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b25" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="y" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('y')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <p:commandButton id="b26" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" value="z" action="#{turnoController.createTurno('z')}" onclick="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=true;"/>
                    <br />
                </h:form>
            <h:graphicImage value="../resources/images/hangman.jpg" width="480" height="400" />
            <h:link outcome="/index" value="#{bundle.CreateJugadorIndexLink}"/>        
        </h:panelGrid>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

and this is the bean I call every time I click the buttonCommand:

```
public String createTurno(String s) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> sesionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
        Integer id = (Integer) sesionMap.get("id_partida");

        Partida p = new Partida();
        p.setIdPartida(id);
        current= new Turno();
        current.setIdPartida(p);
        current.setLetraTurno(s);
        ejbFacade.create(current);
        return "tablero";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is the method I want to call to update the items...

```
public List getLetrasColocadas()
{
    String lc = getFacade().letrasColocadasById(current.getIdPartida());

    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<lc.length(); i++){
        String h = "" + lc.charAt(i) + "";
        lista.add(h);
    }
    return lista;
}
```

the partidaController.getLetrasColocadas() works fine (I have debugged it and it does what I want). The problem is that the the inputText values once they are shown, they never update again if a click a command button for example calling a bean which returns a string with the name of this xhtml file.... it always stays the same.

Any magic I should know about xhtml???

Comment: You need to show the model/managed bean as well so that we could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your current code:

1. You're using `<c:forEach>` for adding `<h:inputText>` components in the view. This will lead to problems if you update these components in the future using an ajax operation. In order to solve this, use `<ui:repeat>` instead. Refer to [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984/1065197) for more info about the topic.
2. Your `<p:commandButton>`s are being disabled after being submitted to the server but never enabled again, so they will stop working after one execution. Add `oncomplete="document.getElementById(this.id).disabled=false;"` to enable it after completing the ajax call. Remember that by default, `<p:commandButton>` has `ajax` property set to `true`.
3. Probably you didn't noticed but your `getLetrasColocadas` method is being invoked more than once in your page. This behavior is well explained here: [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197). How to solve this? Move the business logic from this method to some `loadLetrasColocadas` method and invoke this at the end of `createTurno`, this way you leverage the getter to be a simple `return lista` (assuming this `lista` variable becomes a field of your managed bean).

Now, some warnings on your current design

1. Your `<h:form>` only contains your `<p:commandButton>` elements, thus when submitting the form data to the server you will send **nothing** of the `UIInput` components e.g. the info from the `<h:inputText>` noted above will never be sent to the server.
2. Since you're always returning `"tablero"` in your `createTurno` method, you never execute an ajax call and the whole page is *silently reloaded* (behind the scenes, the response is a forwarding to the same view thus not getting the effect of full redirect from the browser). I recommend to change the `createTurno` from returning a `String` to `void`.

Also, since you're going to use ajax calls only, it would be better to change your managed bean to `@ViewScoped` at least. More info about managed bean scopes: [Communication in JSF 2: Managed Bean Scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes) from BalusC (JSF and Java EE expert).

Answer (score 1):

Well... I discovered that the onclick property of the command button is incompatible with updating the values of the items...